# Language issues when running SQL statements from installshield

Tags: sql, installshield

I have an installshield installation that connects to a SQL Server instance and inserts words from different languages.

After the import runs When I query the data from the database characters from languages with different alphabets are showing up as jumbled text. An example of this would be Russian.

It turns into Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ñ‚ÑƒÑ instead of the correct Russian characters.

How can I fix Installshield so that it inserts the text correctly?

Solution: from Panagiotis Kanavos

I forgot to add the N before the strings.
EG N'[Russian text]'

Comment: What does the query look like? DId you use Unicode literals (add the N prefix before the literal, eg `N'Some String')`. Is the table column `varchar` or `nvarchar`? From the characters, it looks like UTF16 text was stored as single-byte text in the database.

Comment: Bingo, Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos I forgot to add the N prefix before the text. crisis avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the characters (regular pairs,same first character), it looks like UTF16 text was stored as single-byte text in the database. Did you forget to add the `N` prefix in front of any Unicode literals perhaps?